# Sql C# Incorrect syntax near

Tags: c#, sql

I tried to make a code to insert all my data from a grid into a table.
In the grid I display what I need, it's not the problem, or it does not give an error

Displays this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '{'

```
string StrQuery;
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(stringcon))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                            comm.Connection = conn;
                            conn.Open();
                            for (int i = 1; i < bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                           StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO concediati VALUES ("
                            + bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["firstname"].ToString() + ", "
                             + bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["lastname"].ToString() + ", "
                             + bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["CARS"].ToString() + ", "
                             + bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["RENT"].ToString() + ", "
                            + bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["CLIENT"].ToString() + ");";
                        comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
```

Updated with parameters.

```
string StrQuery;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(stringcon))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        comm.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        for (int i = 0; i < bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {


                            StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO concediati(nume,prenume,idcar,idrent,idclient) VALUES (@name,@lastname,@car,@rent,@client)";
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["firstname"].ToString()));
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", Convert.ToString(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["lastname"].ToString()));
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["CARS"].ToString()));
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rent", Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["RENT"].ToString()));
                            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client", Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["CLIENT"].ToString()));



                            comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;


}
```

And now it gives a different error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Pictures: 
[`capture1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJOca.jpg)
[`capture25`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwwmV.jpg)
[`capture25`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkpR9.jpg)
[`capture25`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnUzU.jpg)
[`capture5`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O07QB.jpg)

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[concediati] (
    [Id]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [nume]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [prenume]  VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [idclient] INT          NULL,
    [idrent]   INT          NULL,
    [idcar]    INT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: You won't have this problem if you switch to using parameters instead of concatenating a string with complex expressions. At least one problem is the lack of ticks (') around your string values.

Comment: looking at and/or posting the actual value of StrQuery might make it clearer..

Comment: @Crowcoder i tryed with parameters as you said. But.. it gives me " System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.'"

Comment: That error is not because of parameters, that is because you are trying to put a value in the database that exceeds the size of the column limit. You might need to increase the column length. If you didn't make a syntax error, this code would do the same thing.

Comment: @Crowcoder In table i only have varchar(50) for the lastname and first name and for the cars,rents,clients i have int. I tryed to put convert but it gives me another error ( " System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' ")

Comment: Have you looked at the actual value of `StrQuery`, as @TaW proposed? Could you post that value?

Comment: you an unwanted semicolon(;) at the end : + ");"; should be + ")";

Comment: @styx semicolons are valid statement terminators in T-SQL.

Comment: @oerkelens yes, i looked.. and it's that value that i put in StrQuery.. that query

Comment: Can you try not to use `Addwithvalue`, and create sql parameter objects with correct datatype and length.

Comment: If you are getting input string not in correct format then one of your numeric columns is null or not a number. You should validate the input before assuming you can dump it into a parameter directly from user input.

Comment: Why don't you show us the actual content of StrQuery? Not just the code you use to fill it, but the actual, run time, value of it. That would probably help a lot to solve your problem.

Comment: If you are interested, [I have a basic example of databinding](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid) which is preferable to looping over grid rows. Another problem you have is you are accumulating parameters on the command every loop iteration.

Comment: The information provided is not enough to catch the bug. You should provide some more code like your "Data table and data type of each column", "SQL Query which inserting data" etc.

Comment: @oerkelens i put some pictures in the question

Comment: @ZainArshad i updated my question and i put the data table and data types.. sql query is in the code in StrQuery.

Comment: I think `Convert.ToString(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["firstname"].ToString())` is not returning the value of TextBoxCell object. In one of the attached pictures you can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["firstname"].ToString())` gives you the overriden implementation of `ToString` method. That means you are not getting the actual values from above code.
You should use `bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["firstname"].Value` instead.

Please mark it as answered if it helps.

Comment: Yea it works like bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["firstname"].Value.Value.ToString(); Thank you :). Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) shows a space between the table name and the list of columns, so it would be best to follow that.

Also, you can create the parameters just once outside the loop and set their values in the loop (otherwise you would need to call .Clear() on the parameters and re-create them on every iteration):

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO concediati (nume, prenume, idcar, idrent, idclient) VALUES (@name, @lastname, @car, @rent, @client)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(stringcon))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@name", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 50 });
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@lastname", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 50 });
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@car", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@rent", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@client", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int });

        conn.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string firstName = Convert.ToString(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["firstname"].Value);
            string lastName = Convert.ToString(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["lastname"].Value);
            int car = Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["CARS"].Value);
            int rent = Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["RENT"].Value);
            int client = Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["CLIENT"].Value);

            comm.Parameters["@name"].Value = firstName;
            comm.Parameters["@lastname"].Value = lastName;
            comm.Parameters["@car"].Value = car;
            comm.Parameters["@rent"].Value = rent;
            comm.Parameters["@client"].Value = client;

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and made this change. You can use the following code.

```
 string StrQuery;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(stringcon))
            {

                    for (int i = 0; i < bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
                        comm.Connection = conn;
                        StrQuery = @"INSERT INTO concediati(nume,prenume,idcar,idrent,idclient) VALUES (@name,@lastname,@car,@rent,@client)";
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["firstname"].ToString()));
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", Convert.ToString(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["lastname"].ToString()));
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["CARS"].ToString()));
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rent", Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["RENT"].ToString()));
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client", Convert.ToInt32(bunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows[i].Cells["CLIENT"].ToString()));

                        comm.CommandText = StrQuery;

                        conn.Open();
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();

                    }
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).